# Java Recursive constructor invocation

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int weight;
    int height;

    public Person(String name, int weight, int height){
        this.name=name;
        this.weight=weight;
        this.height=height;
    }

    public Person(String name, int weight){
        this(name, weight);
    }
}
```

Error:(12, 12) java: recursive constructor invocation

What should I change to compile it without errors?

Using IntelliJ 2017.1

Comment: `this(name, weight, DEFAULT_HEIGHT)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public Person(String name, int weight){
        this(name, weight);
    }
```

Yes. That is recursive. Calling the same constructor.

Probably you want to call the other

```
 public Person(String name, int weight){
        this(name, weight,0); // default height 0 
    }
```

`this(name, weight,0);`  calls the other constructor with 3 parameters and Passing height as `0` as there is no height available. Or you can pass whatever the default height.